# How to change address in url (http://localhost:8080/HELLO_WORLD) in NanoHttpd

Tags: java, android, nanohttpd

My query is how to change how to change address in URL (http://localhost:8080/HELLO_WORLD). I change `HELLO_WORLD` to desire word.

```
 @Override
public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {       
    String answer = "";
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(appContext.getAssets().open("block.html")));
        // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading
        String mLine;
        while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            //process line
            answer += mLine;

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //log the exception
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //log the exception
                Log.d("BABAR", "EXception occured in serve()");
            }
        }
    }
    return newFixedLengthResponse(answer);
}
```

please suggest me how to change

Comment: Well what are you trying to change it to? It's still going to have to be localhost... presumably you can ask nanohttpd to start on a different port, but you haven't shown the code that starts the server... What's your actual goal here?

Comment: Did you check nanohttpd's documentation?

Comment: You could implement an `UriRouter`. Have a look into the source of [RouterNanoHTTPD.java](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/master/nanolets/src/main/java/fi/iki/elonen/router/RouterNanoHTTPD.java).

Comment: I want to change that in (http://localhost:8080/website/index.html) how to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t know if this is what you want, but you can try.
You have to follow the steps:

1- Create a local to store your server files;
2-Then change the response in the class that is implementing the NanoHttp server to something like this:

```
@Override
public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
    String answer = "";
    try{
        FileReader filereader = new FileReader(contextoMain.local(localyourstorethefiles)+"/yourfolder/yourfile.html");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(filereader);
    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        answer += line;
    }
    reader.close();

}catch(IOException ioe) {
    Log.w("Httpd", ioe.toString());
}
    return newFixedLengthResponse(answer);
}
```

3 - Then, call the localhost:8080 without putting the 8080/yourfolder/yourfile

Comment: thanx for reply. Any way I change **localhost:8080** to websiteName.com/yourfolder/yourfile.

Comment: php file access or not ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Access what?